# Calculating PDF of a function of random variables via dirac delta integral

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, dirac-delta, geometric-measure-theory

I came across some papers [1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2686109), [2](https://scholarworks.utrgv.edu/mss_fac/106/) and others which use the following formula

$
p(y) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} \, d^{n}x \, \delta(F(\vec{x}) - y) \, p(\vec{x})
$

where $p(y)$ is the PDF of the variable defined by $y=F(\vec{x})$ , also $p(\vec{x})$ is the PDF of the variables $(x_1,x_2,...)$, $\mathcal{X}$ is the $n$-dimensional volume of the variables $\vec{x}$, and $\delta$ is the dirac delta function (see equation 3 in ref [1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2686109) if you prefer a non-vector notation).

However there were no proofs in any of the papers.  My question is, **are there any sources proving this formula?  Or is there some quick intuitive proof?**

My attempt at a proof was as follows.  From Theorem 6.1.5 of Hormander's book, "The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I", I set $\rho = y-F(\vec{x})$ as the $n+1$-dimensional function in the theorem.  From there, after computing the euclidean surface measure, I believe one can show that the cumulative distribution obeys:

$
P(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{a} \,\,p(y)\,dy = \int_{\mathcal{X}'} \,d^{n}x\,\, p(\vec{x})
$

where $\mathcal{X}' := \{x \in \mathcal{X} | F(x) < a \}$ is a suitably restricted volume.  $P(a)$ is the required CDF for the function of random variable $y$.

My formal analysis is a bit rusty so it's possible I got something wrong.  Also, I was finding this method of proof not very intuitive.  My guess is there's a simple trick I'm missing, potentially something obvious from measure theory.