# Finding CDF and PDF of random variable Z=X/Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

$$F_Z(z) = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{yz}       f_X(x) f_Y(y)    dx  dy$$
for Y [Ymin,Ymax] and X>0
$$F_X(yz)F_Y(y) \Big|_Y^{Ymax}   - \int_Y^{Ymax}       F_Y(y) dF_X(yz)  $$

Can I write an equation like this?
Do you think I'm track in the right path?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are continuous the density of $X/Y$ has a relatively simple closed form (though the integral may not be easy to compute). See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the reference [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2686109) .  One can obtain the pdf $f_Z(z)$ for the variable $z = g(x_1,...x_n)$ using the formula:

$
f_{Z}(z) = \int \,d^{n}x \,\,\delta(z-g(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)) f_{X}(x_1, ...,x_n)
$

In your case $x_1=X$, $x_2=Y$, and $z=g(x,y)=x/y$.  Depending on the functions, these integrals may be tough to do.  Getting the CDF can be done by integrating over $z$ up to a point.

Unfortunately, I can't give you a more authoritative source of the above formula that has a proof.  I am actually looking for that myself [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664605/calculating-pdf-of-a-function-of-random-variables-via-dirac-delta-integral).

Intuitively, what the insertion of the delta function does is restrict the volume of integration into the correct domain of the variables $x_i$.